# finding an int that is closest to the avg in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

1. The goal of this was to find nearest no. out of inputted no.s to the avg of the sum of the no.s
2. For some reason it fails to output the correct answer near the final for loop.
3. The code under here is fine

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.*;

   public class ClosesttoAvg{
     public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("input no. elements and then the elements to find 
       closest to avg");   
   double size = sc.nextInt(), load = 0;
   double array[] = new double[(int)size]; 

   //sort all the no.s into an array and add them all up into load 

     for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
     array[i] = sc.nextDouble();
     load = load + array[i];
     }
   System.out.println(load);
   double avg = load/size, record = size, answer = 0;
   //record keeps the smallest distance, answer stores the closest no., 
   //problem is located here
   ```
4. Here is where I have problems though, for some reason it does not save the correct variable

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
     double dist = Math.abs(array[i]-avg);
       if(dist < record){
        answer = array[i];     
       }
     }

    System.out.println(answer);
       }
     }
   ```

Comment: Is this the correct code ? ^^ because `load` alone won't compile, you miss some characters, and to explain that it's not giving the good answer, provide a sample input and give the output of the code

Comment: Here's some [complimentary debugging advice](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Just editted it there, forgot to indent a portion of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should update `record` too. For now it is always `size` and that's why your `answer` can be overwritten.

In `if` in loop add `record = dist;`

Comment: I think that you should initialize `record` with some value and in first iteration change it to first `dist`. To do it you can use `bool flag` or set `record` to `-1` and add `if` in loop. Of course there is few more different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the current element is nearer from the average than the previous, but if it's effectively nearer, you don't save the distance as the smallest one, to use it next, you need to :

```
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
   double dist = Math.abs(array[i]-avg);
   if(dist < record){
      answer = array[i];  
      record = dist;          //<---
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, your answer has to be minimized!!
So keep the answer variable maximum.

```
answer=Double.MAX_VALUE

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
      double dist = Math.abs(array[i]-avg);
        if(dist < record){
         answer = array[i]; 
          record=answer;
        }
      }

 System.out.println(answer);
    }
  }
```